# Optimal number of filters in a Convolutional network

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm building a convolutional Network image classification purposes, my network is inspired by VGG conv network but I changed the number of layers and filters per layers because my image dataset is quite simple.

Nevertheless I'm wondering why the number of fitlers in VGG is always a power of 2 : 64 -> 128 -> 256 -> 512 -> 4096

I guessed that's because each pooling divide the output size by 2 x 2 and therefore one would want to multiply the number of filters by 2.

But I'm still wondering what's the real reason behind this choice; is this for optimization ? is it easier to distribute calculation ? And should I keep this logic in my network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is mainly for optimization. If the network is going to run on a GPU, threads in GPUs come in groups and blocks, normally a group is of 32 threads.

Roughly speaking, if you have a layer with 40 filters, you will need 2 groups = 64 threads. So why not making use of the rest threads and make the layer of 64 filters that can be computed in parallel.